# Rails 6.1 Multiple Database Foreign Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-databases, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I want to create a table with a foreign key in a different database.

Is this possible with rails 6.1?

The guide says [Rails 6.1 will support using has_many relationships and creating 2 queries instead of joining](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#joining-across-databases) but it doesn't say how to do it.

My attempt is this;

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.references :post, foreign_key: { to_database: :primary }
  t.uuid :uuid, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Did you found the solution to this?

Comment: @SWastikThapaliya right now this is not possible in rails 6.1

Comment: We did a lit bit of workaround. 
What we did was we created a relation from the model but did not mention foreign key in the migration file It is adequate for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible at the moment. You can create the relationship in the model and it will work but you can't create a real foreign key in the other databases.